# Error unresolved token (0600000A) & (0600000B) in Visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I get these Error messages in a class i have:

error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600000B) file::GetNumberOfFilesInFolder

error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600000A) file::GetFilesInFolder

error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

My .h file locks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

#include "convert.h"

ref class file
{
public:

static bool GetFilesInFolder(std::string Path,std::vector<std::string> &List);
static bool GetNumberOfFilesInFolder(std::string Path,int &NumOfFiles);
};
```

My .cpp file lock like this:

```
bool GetFilesInFolder(std::string Path,std::vector<std::string> &List)
{
    using namespace std;

    string PathPadd = Path + "*.*";
    wstring PathWstr = convert::StringToWstring(PathPadd);
    const wchar_t* PathWcha = PathWstr.c_str();
    WIN32_FIND_DATA Data;
    HANDLE Hd;

        Hd = FindFirstFile(PathWcha, &Data);

    if(Hd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { return false; }

    do
    {
        if( !(Data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
        {
            WCHAR wc[260];  
            wcscpy_s(wc,Data.cFileName);
            string tmp = convert::WcharArrayToString(wc);
            List.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }while( FindNextFile(Hd, &Data) );

    return true;
}

bool GetNumberOfFilesInFolder(std::string Path,int &NumOfFiles)
{
    using namespace std;

    string PathPadd = Path + "*.*";
    wstring PathWstr = convert::StringToWstring(PathPadd);
    const wchar_t* PathWcha = PathWstr.c_str();
    WIN32_FIND_DATA Data;
    HANDLE Hd;
    int Num = 0;

       Hd = FindFirstFile(PathWcha,&Data);

       if (Hd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { NumOfFiles += Num; return false; }

       do
       {
         if ( !(Data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )  { Num++; }

       } while (FindNextFile(Hd, &Data));

       NumOfFiles += Num;  return true;
}
```

Why do i get these errors?

Comment: You declare and, presumably, call functions named `file::GetFilesInFolder` and `file::GetNumberOfFilesInFolder` - but you  never implement them. Instead, you implement different unrelated functions named `::GetFilesInFolder` and `::GetNumberOfFilesInFolder`

Comment: Thank you @ Igor Tandetnik & @codah, it works perfectly now. I must have forgotten too put file:: before the call of the functions in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `bool file::GetFilesInFolder(...` and `bool file::GetNumberOfFilesInFolder(...`

otherwise the functions are free functions in the global namespace instead of as member functions of your class.